# how to patch an uploaded template on openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have a `template` that I have uploaded to openshift.

```
$ oc get templates | grep jenkins
jenkins-mycompany  Jenkins persistent image 9 (all set) 9
```

When I get the template, you can see the parameters that are set:

```
$ oc get template jenkins-mycompany -o json
```

...

```
{
        "description": "Name of the ImageStreamTag to be used for the Jenkins image.",
        "displayName": "Jenkins ImageStreamTag",
        "name": "JENKINS_IMAGE_STREAM_TAG",
        "value": "jenkins-mycompany:2.0.0-18"
    }
```

I am creating a CI process to build a new Jenkins image and update the template that is uploaded into OpenShift.

I want all params set...

I have tried

1. `oc process -f deploy.yml --param-file=my-param-file | oc create -f-`
2. `cat mydeploy.json | oc create -f-`

The only way I can get this to work is to do an `oc delete templates jenkins-mycompany` and then `oc create -f deploy.yml`.

I want to just patch the value of that one parameter so when I build `2.0.0-19`, I just patch the template.

Comment: Why not making the "jenkins-mycompany:2.0.0-18" a parameter of the template, that needs to be provided when processing it?

Comment: @ptrk i would prefer the params to be set so my consumers just need to process the default template and it works out of the box. the consumers can override params.

Comment: There are two levels of providing params. One is the template itself, so you can have a default and optionally override it when processing the template. Then there's the DeploymentConfig params you can override again. So you can have the consumers process the default or override.

Answer (score 0):

[Openshift CLI Reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.11/pdf/cli_reference/OpenShift_Container_Platform-3.11-CLI_Reference-en-US.pdf)

You want to use the patch command like so:

`oc patch <object_type> <object_name> -p <changes>`

For example,

`oc patch template jenkins-mycompany -p '{"spec":{"unschedulable":true}}'`